# Looker visualization mysql issue

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

I connect to mysql server to visualize data into looker.
I have column which has dates in text format.
The table is as follow:-

| property_id | year_month |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021_01 |
| 33 | 2021_01 |
| 356 | 2021_03 |
| 32 | 2022_04 |

I would like to convert this year month column to date, so that I can add date filter in my visual ... I am left with the impression that I should concat 01 as a day for that column and then parse date as follow

```
PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", REPLACE(CONCAT(year_month_extra, "_01"), "_", "-"))
```

I recieve error from the visual "inproper configuration"

> Error with SQL statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'year_month AS CHAR), CAST('*01' AS CHAR)), '*',
> '-'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS DATE) AS qt' at line 1

Could you please help?
Thank you very much

Comment: Mysql does not have a parse_date function. If that function is in looker, then looker generates an incorrect sql statement for transforming the date. Not sure what you can do in looker to fix this. In mysql you can create a view or generated column to do this transformation.

Comment: Try changing it to `PARSE_DATE("%Y_%m_%d", CONCAT(year_month_extra, "_01"))`